# How To Print Specific Value Using For Loops

Tags: c++, arrays, function

I have a function to print the array like this:

```
void letter_function(char cards[]) {
 for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    cout << "\n" << "|" << letters[i] << "|";       
 }
cout << endl;
}

char letters[6] = {'A','B','C','D','E','F'};
```

I'm trying to print specific values from this function. For example, The function will print the array letters with the `"|"`.

Now, let say that I want to print the first letter with that symbol. How can I do that. I thought of using another loop but nothing works and I'm not sure how to incorporate the function inside a loop to do what I want.

Output if I want to print the first letter from the function should be:
`|A|`

Comment: Please show the desired output, that will help clarify the question.

Comment: I still don't understand, why would you want a *loop* to print a single element? Please show how you would call this function.

Comment: Now that you said that I think I can do that with an if statement. However, I'm struggling on how to choose certain value from a function to print out in the main. If I do something like `letters[0]` to print letter `A` but with `|A|`

Comment: Just index into it, e.g. if you want to print the 3rd element, do `cout << '|' << letters[2] << '|';`

Comment: I understand I could do that. But, since I have the function already and I will write a lot of if statement I want the lines to be short and not write what I already have in the function.

Comment: Do you want to print only one of the values in the array between "|"? Or all values of the array?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, I believe what you are wanting to do is to be able to print anywhere from a single letter, to the entire array. So you could do something like this:

```
void letter_function(char cards[], int start, int end) {
 for (int i = start; i < end; i++) {
    cout << "\n" << "|" << letters[i] << "|";       
 }
cout << endl;
}

char letters[6] = {'A','B','C','D','E','F'};
```

This would allow you to vary the starting position and the ending position to meet your desired index or range.

Another option is to pass in a character instead of the starting and ending index and add an if statement.

```
void letter_function(char cards[], char target) {
    for (int i = start; i < end; i++) {
        if(letter[i] == target) cout << "\n" << "|" << letters[i] << "|";       
     }
    cout << endl;
    }
    
    char letters[6] = {'A','B','C','D','E','F'};
```

if you could clarify the desired effect of the function I would be able to give a more precise answer.

Comment: Okay, I do know I'm not explaining this well. I confused myself too. So, if you run the function you will see the list of letters with the `"|"` next to them? Now, what I want to do since I already have the function that prints and appoints the symbol, I want to be able to choose any specific letter FROM the function to print out. I would like to know if that's possible?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to print just one of the characters while maintaining the loop you can just add an if statement to the loop.

```
void letter_function(char cards[], int index) {
for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
      if (i == index) {
         cout << "\n" << "|" << letters[i] << "|";   
      }   
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

Comment: That does work, but I'm trying to do something with this program I'm making. The function has to stay the way I have it because later I want to be able to do some if statement and choose specific values from that function without having to write everything again or adding the same cout line to all if statements.

Comment: I think I understand what you mean. You want to print one index that you choose while maintaining the for loop. Correct? I edited my answer for that. Please check it again.

Comment: @Chris Wilhelms actually has the answer. Thank you anyways for the help, I appreciate it!